# How to organise icons into places (like the iPhone homescreen)

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I'm creating an application which has a home screen that looks like the native iPhone home screen. I don't have any pages but I wanted to enable dragging and dropping of the icons when you hold them to organise them into different places.

Is this possible? How hard would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 framework provides a [launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) class that supports this kind of view, but please think before using it. iPhone apps should look like iPhone apps, not like iPhone home screen.

Comment: Ok thanks! And we've got so many pages/sections of the app, I think we're going to have to use it. After all Facebook use it and their app home screen looks/functions good.

Comment: Even Facebook's former lead iOS developer thinks it was a bad idea https://twitter.com/#!/joehewitt/statuses/94559607212617728